# Specifying specific cost allocation tags for aws batch compute resources

Tags: aws-batch, aws-billing

I would like to tag specific job IDs or jobs that originate from a specific job definition in AWS batch so I can track costs better.

I have been attempting to do it in AWS cost explorer. I can filter on a job definiton, but then no costs populated. The only tag that works, if you can call it a tag is "no tag key". I'm not sure how to proceed. I would share a little more, but it's for my company and I'd like to post a photo of the cost explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can help with the tagging but one of my buddies recently started using a company called Zesty to keep better track of their costs and reduce them. Its an AWS billing tool that automates buying/selling 3 yr EC2 RIs on their behalf to get the lowest prices in the market. Hes been saying it completely offloads the workload of navigating the RI marketplace, and its pushed them to over 95% coverage.

I have checked out their website a bit and looks like they have a buy back guarantee in case of over-provisioning too. I think he said they also have a dashboard to get insight into exactly how their costs are divided out, even which resources are going unused etc. which could help solve ur problem.

Not sure if u want to go that route but I can see if I can get his guy's contact info.

Comment: Thank you AaaaaTayyyy. I work for a small company too. We initially looked at some other companies to help but decided to try to do it in house. I contacted AWS billing because there's no "tagging" department listed in the support console. They we're of zero help when they responded. I've set this project aside for the time being. The documentation isn't very clear either. I appreciate your help.